# Google AdMob - "initialized without an application id" error

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

I'm trying to use Google AdMob in my app. However, the app keeps crashing on launch. I believe I've initialized AdMob properly, since I added the required `GADApplicationIdentifier` key and value to my `Info.plist` file, and I also have `GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)` in `AppDelegate.swift`.

Here is my error log:

```
2019-10-02 00:23:18.731486-0400 App Name[15066:162231] [Crashlytics] Version 3.14.0 (144)

2019-10-02 00:23:18.741556-0400 App Name[15066:162311] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

2019-10-02 00:23:18.742118-0400 App Name[15066:162335] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

2019-10-02 00:23:18.743045-0400 App Name[15066:162335] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

2019-10-02 00:23:18.746628-0400 App Name[15066:162311] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

2019-10-02 00:23:18.746676-0400 App Name[15066:162336] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

2019-10-02 00:23:18.747969-0400 App Name[15066:162311] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

2019-10-02 00:23:18.748361-0400 App Name[15066:162337] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

2019-10-02 00:23:18.787064-0400 App Name[15066:162231] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID. Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to set GADApplicationIdentifier with a valid App ID. Google Ad Manager publishers, follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist'
```

This is with Swift 5 and iOS 13.

Answer (score 18):

Add `GADIsAdManagerApp` with positive value to your Info.plist file like this:

[image]

This fixed crash for me.

Comment: Awesome!!  Did NOT see anything on Google's site about the GADisAdManager.  Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Thanks. I had the same issue and adding of this key in the info.plist helped me.

Comment: Me too, it worked well... thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Search for Info.plist on your project and add parameter named **GADIsAdManagerApp** it should be Boolean and set it to YES.

then run and you will see the success. Info.plist should be like that:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this error also, while setting **GADIsAdManagerApp** as true does fix it there is nothing on GoogleAdMobs docs that says to do this.

My problem was that I had not put in my payment details and I had not been verified the verification took 24 hours and I was only able to input my details by using Firefox, Chrome and Safari did not want to work with AdMobs website. However once I had waited everything was working as it should've!